# the lowest interrupt priority is ignored by the kernel and is not processed

Tags: arm, interrupt

I am working with an armv8-2 core and a Rockchip RK3568 processor
I have set up two interrupts, a timer and a uart. At the same time, if one of them has an interrupt priority of 0xF0 (the lowest), then the interrupt is not called and is not processed. If I change the priority to a different value, everything works fine. At the same time, the pending bit is set in the GIC registers for the corresponding interrupts (when the priority is set to 0xF0), but no processing occurs. I don't understand what is the reason for this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how write in arm documentation (mask priority) my 0xF0 priority is "idle priority" and he is masked always